# C#, Усложненное разделение строки на подстроки

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте,  у меня возникла проблема с сплитом строки.
По заданию я должен взять строку и определить есть ли в ней определенные сепараторы, говорящие нам что строка является массивом. Строка достается из файла, но это не принципиально.

Пример:

Условие таково, строка является массивом только если в ней есть **','** либо **':'** , не оба(первое попавшееся условие является разделителем, а следовательно при попадании на другой сепаратор он рассматривается как простая часть строки, а не разделитель)

При этом **"\,"** и **"\:"** не являются определителями массива.

Следовательно при:

```
string s="a,b,f:g";
```

нужно создать массив array:

```
array[0]="a";
array[1]="b";
array[2]="f:g";
```

А при:

```
string s="a,b\,f\";
```

создается:

```
array[0]="a";
array[1]="b\,f\";
```

Если есть возможность, подскажите как этого добиться?
Я пробовал сделать сплит, но тогда я не знаю какой именно сепаратор использовался.(а мне нужно знать для последующего восстановления строки в изначальный вид)

**UPD**

Я сделал метод, который выглядит не очень элегантно, но частично справляется с заданием(дает информацию по какому сепаратору можно разделить строку)

```
static char IsArray(string line)
{
    string s;
    s=line;
    s=s.Replace("\\,", "");
    s=s.Replace("\\:", "");
    int firstSeparator = s.IndexOf(',');
    int secondSeparator = s.IndexOf(':');
    if (firstSeparator > secondSeparator
       && secondSeparator != -1)
        firstSeparator = secondSeparator;
    if (firstSeparator != -1)
        return s[firstSeparator];
    if (secondSeparator != -1)
        return s[secondSeparator];
    return '\0';

}
```

Остается вопрос, как разделить строку на данный сепаратор игнорируя **"\,"** и **"\:"**

Comment: сплитить можно с помощью регулярки

Comment: Мне стыдно.. но мне это ничего не говорит

Comment: [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я такое бы сделал с помощью сплита по регулярному выражению с негативным просмотром назад:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s="a,b,f:g";
        char separator = IsArray(s);
        string[] ss = Regex.Split(s, "(?<!\\\\)" + separator);
        foreach(string a in ss){
            System.Console.WriteLine(a);    
        }
        s = "a,b\\,f\\";
        separator = IsArray(s);
        ss = Regex.Split(s, "(?<!\\\\)" + separator);
        foreach(string a in ss){
            System.Console.WriteLine(a);    
        }

    }

    static char IsArray(string line)
    {
        string s;
        s=line;
        s=s.Replace("\\,", "");
        s=s.Replace("\\:", "");
        int firstSeparator = s.IndexOf(',');
        int secondSeparator = s.IndexOf(':');
        if (firstSeparator > secondSeparator
           && secondSeparator != -1)
            firstSeparator = secondSeparator;
        if (firstSeparator != -1)
            return s[firstSeparator];
        if (secondSeparator != -1)
            return s[secondSeparator];
        return '\0';
    }
}
```

> a
>   b
>   f:g
>   a
>   b\,f\

Суть конструкции регулярки с негативным просмотром назад `(?<!\\\\),` или `(?<!\\\\):` такова, что будет браться во внимание только те символы `,` или `:`, перед которыми нету обратного слеша. То есть регулярка находит нужный символ, затем возвращается назад (`?<!`) и если перед символом обратный слеш, то она не считает это  место совпадением с регуляркой.

[запускабельный код на tutorialspoint](http://goo.gl/dYV5Hv)

Comment: Я извиняюсь, оказалось что я не могу использовать регулярные выражения, есть ли другой способ?

Comment: @Demolver, почему не можете?

Comment: Уточнение было, что нужно пользоваться стандартными библиотеками c#, я на него не обратил внимания просто

Comment: @Demolver, эм, `Regex` - это стандартный класс c# :)

Comment: Не знал, тогда спасибо большое

Comment: Без регулярок только руками парсить строку. Запоминаете начальный индекс, проходите по строке, находите разделитель, добавляете, например в `List` подстроку от начального индекса и текущего индекса, начальный делаете текущим + 1 и т.д. Крайний случай - последняя подстрока, там костыль нужен. 
Но `Regex` стандартная библиотека, так что такие костыли вам не нужно лепить. Разве что ради попрактиковаться, решив эту задачу разными способами.